# VS 2017 python program doesn't start

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-2017

Installed a fresh VS 2017 with Python 3.6 (64-bit) and wrote a little "hello World" program; when starting the program with the python interpreter in the cmd environment everything is fine, but when i try to start the program within Vs2017 (single step debuger, debber start >) hust nothing happens :-( Where can i find log files to investigate the problem?

Windows 2010 Pro 10.0.16299 Build 16299

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017

VisualStudio.15.Release/15.4.4+27004.2009
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02556

Installierte Version: Community

Python   3.0.17310.2
Stellt IntelliSense, Projekte, Vorlagen, Debuggen, interaktive Fenster und weitere Unterstützung für Python-Entwickler bereit.

Python – Django-Unterstützung   3.0.17310.2
Stellt Vorlagen und Integration für das Django-Webframework bereit.

Python – IronPython-Unterstützung   3.0.17310.2
Stellt Vorlagen und Integration für IronPython-basierte Projekte bereit.

Python – Unterstützung für die Profilerstellung   3.0.17310.2
Profilerstellungsunterstützung für Python-Projekte.

Python – Unterstützung für VC-Projekte   3.0.17262.1
Bietet Unterstützung für das Starten von C++-Projekten mit aktivierter Python-Debugfunktion.

Update 6.12.17
Recreated a fresh new project from scratch (even stated VS2017 new);
see project environment / project explorer:

[Screen Shot Project environment / projedt explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKsOy.png) 
Startupfile is right (app-name.py)

starting program works as expected; 
starting (with a breakpoint set) using "start with debugger" no effect; 
I didn't change any VS settings - just use it as installed; 
pylint returned no errors;

Comment: Please enable the Python Exception under Debug->Windows->Exception Settings window, and then debug your app again, maybe you could get some exception messages. In addition, the latest VS2017 was the version 15.4.5, please also update it to the latest version, debug a simple Python app again. Right click the Python Environment under Solution explore window, and view all Environment, change it to other Environment, view the result.

Comment: Thanks Jack for the hints; I've updated my VS to 15.4.5 but still the program doesn't start with debugger; wenn staring the program without debugger (from the VS) new Window opens and prints my "Hello World" as expected. strange, isn't it? I could explore the Python Environemnt = lists as "Python 3.6(64-bit)(globaler Standard) and then some more "modules" aka astroid (1.5.3) and so on

Comment: If your app works well using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)", but not work using debugging(F5) directly, we would think about the Environment.(1) Run VS as the admin.(2) Close all third party tools/processes in your windows like firewall/anti-virus software. (3) Just reset your VS settings, and then create a new project, debug it again.

Comment: first run as admin - no change; the closed all virus protection - no change; third created new project - still no change; any idea, where VS is going to write a log/err/... file where I can check was happens; running the program without debug from VS always workls :-(

Comment: Whether other project(maybe a C# console app) still has this issue or just the Python project during debugging? Do you use the windows 10 64 bit? Do you get any warning or Exception during debugging? Maybe you could visit the output or Error list window, or the Event viewer, check it again.

Comment: Really strange - just checked my VS vb.net project (just imported from VS2015) and debugger started as expected without any problem; and yes, using Windows10 64 bit; and didn't found any entry in the error list or event window

Comment: If other project has no this issue, maybe it was not the debugging tool issue. Please clean and rebuild your project, and then view your project properties window->General /Debug option. (1) Please make sure that the startup file was the Appname.py file. (2) The Launch mode was "Standard Python launcher", and then debug it again. Do you reset your VS settings in your side? Maybe not debug your app directly, please add a Breakpoint to your app, and then debug it again. View the result.

Comment: See my changes/results in the updated question.

Comment: Updated VS2017 to the latest release 15.5.1 - no changes, debugger still not starting while code works without debugger

Comment: Do you test it in other VS machine? How about creating a blank solution? And then add your project to this blank solution. Sorry for that I couldn't repro this issue in my side. Maybe you could uninstall your VS, re-install it again.